# Ant: what is the equivalent command in bash

Tags: bash, ant, antlr, build.xml

I was reading [a tutorial](http://dexvis.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/a-tale-of-two-grammars/) with the following ant script in build.xml

```
<project name="calculator4" default="generate" basedir=".">
    <property name="src" location="src" />
    <property name="gen" location="gen" />
    <property name="src" location="src" />
    <property name="package" value="calculator4" />

    <target name="generate">
        <mkdir dir="${gen}/${package}" />
        <java classname="org.antlr.v4.Tool" classpathref="classpath" fork="true">
            <arg value="-o" />
            <arg path="${gen}/${package}" />
            <arg value="-lib" />
            <arg path="${src}/${package}" />
            <arg value="-listener" />
            <arg value="${src}/${package}/Calculator.g4" />
        </java>
    </target>
```

As I don't know much about ant and don't want to use it, I try to translate the command to bash like so

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool -o gen/calculator4 -lib src/calculator4 -listener src/calculator4/Calculator.g4
```

But this is wrong as it generates files in gen/calculator4/src/calculator4 as supposed to the correct behavior of generating files in gen/calculator4

Is there something special going on with ${} other than direct substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative path for generated files matches the relative path for input files. Since you specified `src/calculator4/Calculator.g4` as the input file, the output files will be `src/calculator4/*.java`.

1. Change directories so the working directory is the same folder where `Calculator.g4` is.
2. Remove the `-lib src/calculator4` argument.
3. Change the `-o` argument to `-o ../../gen/calculator4`.
4. Pass just `Calculator.g4` as the final argument to the command.

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean Ant is doing something special with ${} in the path, since I never needed to use ../.. when building with build.xml?

Comment: @user2191332 The output is relative to the current directory. If you change the current directory, the relative path to the output directory must be changed as well if you want things to appear in the same location.

Comment: What I was wondering is why using <arg value="${src}/${package}/Calculator.g4" /> is different from running <arg value="src/calculator4/Calculator.g4" />? The former correctly puts the generated file in gen/calculator4 as supposed to inside gen/calculator4/src/calculator4